# What does "石井ん家" (abbreviation) mean?

Tags: translation

In sentence: "放課後とりま石井ん家に集合な!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「Person's Name/Nickname or Personal Pronoun + ん + [家]{ち}」

is an informal way of saying "***~~'s place/house***".  「家」 is read 「ち」 in this expression.  This reading is exceptional, so it must be mentioned.

「～～ + **ん**ち」＝「～～ + **の** + うち」

「とりま」 is a slangy shortened form of 「**とり**あえず、**ま**あ」, which loosely means "for the time being", "first off", etc.

> "After school, we're going to meet at Ishii's place first, alright?"

Comment: Is とりま a relatively new phrase? Never heard that before.

Comment: Also, if the `Person's Name/Nickname or Personal Pronoun` ends in ん, the following ん is omitted (e.g. あきちゃん家).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the ん is just a contracted の in this case.

> 放課後とりま石井***の***家に集合な!　→　We're meeting at Ishii's house after school!

---

**Edit**: Apparently 「とりま」 is a slang contraction of 「とりあえず、まあ」.

Comment: I think it's not a name as well, why would you call your friend with both names? It must be some kind of location.

Comment: とりま is  a recent slangish contraction for "とりあえず、まあ".

Answer (score 1):

ん[家]{ち} is a contraction of の[家]{うち}. It goes with names, like 石井ん家 "Ishii's place", or personal pronouns, like あんたん家 "your place" or 私ん家 "my place".

If the name ends in ん the ん of ん家 is omitted, e.g. あきちゃん家 "Aki's place".

It's a very common way to say "[somebody]'s place/house". This reading of 家 even has its own dictionary entry, for example in 大辞林

> **ち**【<sup>▽</sup>家】〔「うち（家）」に助詞「の」が付いた「のうち」の転「んち」から〕
>
> 家。うち。「ぼくん—」「君ん—」